# Converting a sentence to passive with "would"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, translation

I know how passive voice is created in general:

> He is rich => He is said to be rich.
>
> People say that he's not able to win => He's said not to be able to
>   win.

There is a sentence:

> He would like to increase our profit.

How can I make a passive of that, I am confused because of the "would".
How to transform this sentence to a passive voice?

> He is said to (?)

Comment: Just for clarification: are you trying to convert the *would* itself to passive voice? It's a modal verb. The exercise is probably asking for "He would like for our profits to be increased" instead.

Comment: No, it is not an exercise, I'm just curious. I modified the question.

Comment: Ah okay. Well, in that case it's "He's said to want", obviously.

Comment: Also it is the same as if there was "want" actually in the original sentence? But isnt "would like" different in meaning than "want"?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the grammatical tense then I'd say:

> It is said that he would like to increase our profit

Otherwise i'd ignore `would` and say:

> He is said to like to increase our profit

Comment: Something about that second version is wrong.

Comment: @tchrist If you say `He's said to liking...`, it's correct but has a different meaning. Also `said to like increasing...` is correct, but still doesn't match the meaning he's looking for. So although my 2nd version isn't that good, i believe it's grammatically correct and it means what he wants to say...

Comment: No, **He's said to liking* is wrong no matter what the context. And although *he is said to wish to increase our profit* would be fine if cumbersome, I too am unhappy with your version.

Comment: @TimLymington Yeah you're right `said to liking` is absolutely wrong. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be "Increasing our profit is his desire."

Comment: But that’s not passive. “Increasing our profit would be liked by him” is passive but ugly.